# Parsing exception when using int-groovy:script tag

Tags: groovy, xml-parsing, xsd, spring-integration

I am working on a Spring Integration project and writing a sample transformer using Groovy. Given below is the sample from the Spring configuration file --

```
<int:transformer input-channel="channel8" output-channel="channel9">
   <int-groovy:script>
        <![CDATA[
        if (!payload.equals('hello')) {
            throw new RuntimeException('invalid payload')
        }
        payload
         ]]>

    </int-groovy:script>    

</int:transformer>
```

I have imported the following namespace and also there is no error shown for the xml Spring configuration file in Eclipse editor.

xmlns:int-groovy="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/groovy"

However on running my program, I am seeing the following error --

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 60; columnNumber: 24; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'int-groovy:script'.
  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorRep‌​orter.java:437)
```

I am not sure on what I am missing here. Any help on this appreciated.

Comment: Printing the stacktrace in depth:

Comment: Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 60; columnNumber: 24; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'int-groovy:script'.
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:437)
 at

Comment: Did you add the int-groovy schemaLocation as well?

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but not sure how to do it. Could you kindly give an example?

Comment: If you use Spring Tool Suite (STS) or the plugins for Spring, the editprs support it directly (via the namespace tab). If you are creating the files manually, take a look at some of the test cases, such as... https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-groovy/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/groovy/config/GroovyHeaderEnricherTests-context.xml Simply add the namespace and then tell the parser where to find the schema for that namespace.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I have tried to give the location also like xsi:schemaLocation=http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/groovy http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/groovy/spring-integration-groovy-2.2.xsd. But in this case, I am getting the following error --Configuration problem: Either the 'location' attribute or inline script text must be provided, but not both.

Comment: You have to use the http forms I cited - Spring has meta data (in META-INF/spring-schemas) to map the XSDs to a physical file in the jar.

Answer (score 0):

I think your missing the 'spring-integration-groovy-x.x.x.RELEASE.jar' file from your runtime path